# Invalid flag -parameters in java 1.7

Tags: java, spring, java-7

I have the task to create the spring-boot application using Java 7.

So, as usual, I created a template on start.spring.io resource and open him via `File -> New -> Project from Existing Sources...`

When I run with `jdk-8`, everything works fine, but when I change JDK to version 1.7 (also I change `java-version` in `pom.xml`) I get a compilation error:

> Error:java: invalid flag: -parameters

### Screenshot:

[image]

### Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.exercise</groupId>
<artifactId>quadratic</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>quadratic</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have no created any classes in this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.1 requires Java 8 as per [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements):

> Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE requires Java 8 and is compatible up to Java 11 (included). Spring Framework 5.1.4.RELEASE or above is also required.

You must downgrade to Spring Boot 1.5 if you plan to use Java 7, as per [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.19.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements):

> Spring Boot 1.5.19.RELEASE requires Java 7 and Spring Framework 4.3.22.RELEASE or above. You can use Spring Boot with Java 6 with some additional configuration. See Section 85.11, “How to use Java 6” for more details.

Answer (score 6):

`-parameters` is new feature introduced in java 1.8.  The error is expected when it is used in java 1.7.

So please update java version to 1.8 if you want this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Unsupported version of spring boot for Java 7. Pleaser downgrade and try

Answer (score 0):

For me the JAVA_HOME was pointing to Java 1.7 although the `java -version` gave me Java 1.8 version.

So in CMD I just set the JAVA_HOME to 1.8 folder, and aligned also the `PATH`
like

`set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin:%PATH%`