# Maven build error: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: -parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a SpringBoot application which build and runs perfectly in intelliJ (i.e. if from within the IntelliJ gui I do a maven clean and install).

Howevwer, if I try run `mvn clean install` from the cmd line, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project nexct-approval-service: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: -parameters -> [Help 1]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid flag: -parameters
```

Any ideas on how to build the application from the cmd line?

I have my JAVA_HOME set to 1.7, because there are other apps I run on 1.7. This app runs on Java 14, so I have that set in my pom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.nexct</groupId>
    <artifactId>nexct-approval-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>nexct-approval-service</name>
    <description>Approval Service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.release>${java.version}</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jsk.version>2.2.3</jsk.version>
        <start-class>com.nexct.approvalservice.NexctApprovalServiceApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.jini</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsk-platform</artifactId>
            <version>${jsk.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0-b170201.1204</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0-b170127.1453</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Travellinck approval component client API-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.travellinck.approval</groupId>
            <artifactId>approval-engine-soap-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-ts</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: This answer suggests that it is a result of a java version issue. How do I change the java version to 14 for only this project and not the others?  I thought this can be done by adding `<java.version>14</java.version>` to the POM? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54700277/invalid-flag-parameters-in-java-1-7

Comment: I have also tried adding this to the pom, with no success: `<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<source>${java.version}</source>
<target>${java.version}</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>`

Comment: this may help; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654557/how-to-set-specific-java-version-to-maven

Comment: Hi Habil, thanks for the post.  I have tried setting the java version in the POM.  I would like to avoid having to set the JAVA_HOME, because I need to deploy this to multiple environments which all use java 1.7 (this will be the only project using java 14).  So if it can be configured in its POM that is ideal. But I just cannot get the POM to force it to build with java 14.

Comment: ok, I think you may use embedded mvn. Easly edit .bat file and point it to preferred JDK?

Comment: Thanks, I took your advise and set it just before I build it with:  `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: Mixing 2.4.0-SNAPSHOT with 2.3.1.RELEASE ...will cause trouble... fix this first...